# How to inherit structure members from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I wrote a simple c++ code to do some library management with inheritance concepts. I stuck with some inherited structure problem and some global variable problem.
my code:

header file:

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H

#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int count_emp;
static int m_nCountBook;

class employee 
{
protected:
    typedef struct
    {
        char employee_name[20];
        int employee_id;
        char employee_dept[20];
        char status_emp[10];
    } stemp;

public:
    stemp emp[10];  

    void add_employee();
    void display_employee();
};

class library : public employee
{
protected:
    typedef struct
    {   
        char book_name[20];
        int book_id;
        char author[20];
        char status_book;
    } stlib;

public:
    stlib lib[10];

    void addBook();
    void showBook();
    void bookTaken();
    void bookReturn();
};

#endif
```

The concept is when i implement `bookTaken()` function in another file ,it should be check the employee id and add the `status_emp` as taken. if previously status of employee as taken , then not allowed . How i define that function using both structures ? Again one more problem is here  that `static int count_emp` ;
`static int m_nCountBook`; are static .How can i get to another file ?

Comment: When using C++ do yourself a favor and use `std::string` instead of char arrays and `std::vector` instead of all other arrays. Does your code compile with the nested structs declared protected, but used in the public interface?

Comment: In addition, think about your class `employee`. *Is* it an employee? To me it seems like it should be named employe**r**.

Comment: Agree with @nvoigt . This does seem confused. Why is a library a specialization of an mployee? Why does an employee have up to 10 names, ID, etc...?

Comment: And what does `bookTaken()` have to do with an `employee_id`? Is it the id of the person who borrowed the book, or of the library (which, in this design, is an employee)? Or do you mean the `book_id` and `status_book`? Voting to close.

Comment: Why library extends employer? An employer can have many books.

Comment: Yes, but a library is a library, not an employer. The employer can have a library, but that would be a contains relationship, not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your two global variables. They should probably be instance fields of your library class.

Most likely, you won't need them at all if you use the `stl` properly. For example by replacing all arrays by `std::vector`s except for char arrays that should be `std::string`.